# Convert data from text file to tuples

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have a text file in this form:

```
ID1

NUMBER1

NUMBER2 

ID2

NUMBER3

NUMBER4
```

The desired outpt is:
`(ID1,NUMBER1),(ID1,NUMBER2),(ID2,NUMBER3)(ID2,NUMBER4)`.

I think it must be converted to tuples.
But I am still stuck on how to get the desired output.

This is my code so far:

```py
with open("outfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
          print(line, type(line))
```

I will get the file line by line with type "str"

Comment: what form is that? is it a file? is it something else? what have you tried?

Comment: Are the strings hard-coded in your program or from a file? What is the data structure of your strings? Is it a list of strings or just a long new line separated string? Show us some code

Comment: @Craicerjack yes it is file. I read it in python line by line readline().

Comment: @MohammadDeyaaFattal Please edit your question and add the code

Comment: Does your text file contain empty lines like shown in the example or not?

Comment: @AbdelhakimAKODADI yes it contains empty lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
tuples = []
with open("outfile.txt") as f:
    current_id = ''
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ID'):
            current_id = line
        elif line.startswith('NUMBER'):
            tuples.append((current_id, line))
print(tuples)
```

Comment: it works. thank you @Abdelhakim AKODADI